# Attach custom headers before every fetch request in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can i configure my react application to attach some custom request before every http request? We had $httpProvider in angularjs for the same purpose. What is the way of doing it in react?

Comment: what do you use to send requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the call in a function and add the headers?

```
global.FetchWithHeaders = async function(verb, url, data){
    const request = {
            method: verb,
            headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '[Example Header Token]' }
        };

    if (data)    {
        request.body = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    const responseObj = await fetch(url, request)
        .then(function(response){
            //Do something with response
            console.log(response);
        });

    return responseObj;
};
```

Could sit in a base Component or in global like above. Depends how you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

react does not use any embedded http provider function. You must use an external module like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). Also available: [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Please have a look at [facebook with ajax post](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) to understand when fetching data in react lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

React, unlike angular is not a framework, but merely a view layer. To do data fetching, routing, managing state, etc. you would have to use other libraries. You could use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which is pretty good. You can configure it like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
var http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
})
http.get('/some-endpoint').then(...)
```